# Facebook sharing not displaying meta data unless url passed through debugger

Tags: facebook, share, meta-tags

I have a strange problem with Facebook sharing. I have a news portal and when I try to share some news, half of them are sharing fine, and half are not recognized at all, just the link is shared without Title, Image and Description.

The news portal is in PHP Codeigniter, and here are the meta tags that every news link has, and they are correct when I see Page Source.

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="the number"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="the full url of the page" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of the news story" />
<meta property="og:description" content="The introduction of the story" />
<meta property="og:image" content="full link of the image"/>
```

I checked there isn't anything common for the stories that Facebook does not take the meta data. I tried with everytype od image, and with many different resolutions, even with the minimum resolution 200x200 but there is no success.

The only solution is to put the link in the Facebook debugger and then it is working fine. After that you can share it normal, but this is wasting of a lot of time and energy to put half of the links in the debugger before sharing...

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does debugger return some warnings or errors (like APP_ID, domain)

Comment: og:image should be larger: Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image '...' will be used instead.

Here is what it says. The image is big enough (665x480 at least), I tried with auto crop and giving to Facebook exact 200x200 but it's the same warning. It says that the image is small, and he will get "another" image but it is getting the same image, the same url that is provided in the og:image parameter.

Can this be the reason why it is not recognizing some links at all? what am I missing?

Comment: What else should I try to fix this? Any help?

Comment: I haven't got such a problem. Can you post some example link (blank page with OG).